# Writing Adobe Image Resource Block metadata to a tiff Image using c#

Tags: c#, image, metadata, tiff

I had posted this question on Adobe forum but did not get any solution. Well here it goes..

Background :

I am working on a small .NET application which reads the tiff file and performs some metadata related operations on it.
The program works fine with all of the tiff Images that are taken from photoshop. I have recieved a tiff file from the client which does not work with the program.
I checked the metadata info for the file using imagemagik following is the output

```
 
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 6986x3754+0+0
  Resolution: 96x96
  Print size: 72.7708x39.1042
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Base type: TrueColor
  Endianess: MSB
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 37 (0.145098)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 215.041 (0.843299)
      standard deviation: 48.8483 (0.191562)
      kurtosis: 0.845012
      skewness: -1.09632
    Green:
      min: 25 (0.0980392)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 213.399 (0.836859)
      standard deviation: 50.853 (0.199424)
      kurtosis: 0.908226
      skewness: -1.09806
    Blue:
      min: 21 (0.0823529)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 210.495 (0.825471)
      standard deviation: 53.6527 (0.210403)
      kurtosis: 0.124965
      skewness: -0.929882
    Alpha:
      min: 64 (0.25098)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 254.948 (0.999796)
      standard deviation: 2.56957 (0.0100768)
      kurtosis: 2437.44
      skewness: 49.3893
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 159.747 (0.626458)
      standard deviation: 44.321 (0.173808)
      kurtosis: 48.4205
      skewness: -8.00071
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 6986x3754+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-02-15T21:18:37+06:00
    date:modify: 2014-02-09T16:29:10+06:00
    signature: a5c4a9415437ee2d3b0c3d860b30c5367f73fe7553c3f54923caf6da4b9e4623
    tiff:alpha: unassociated
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 3754
  Artifacts:
    filename: C:\Users\Jane\TiffPathOperation\bin\Debug\Example1client_no_path.tiff
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 14.6MB
  Number pixels: 26.23M
  Pixels per second: 54.64MB
  User time: 0.484u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.479
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-4 2013-10-26 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org


Unlike other tiff images this image does not contain 8bim profile information, which is required for proper execution of the program

Profiles:
  Profile-8bim: 11720 bytes
  Profile-icc: 3144 bytes
    Description: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
    Manufacturer: IEC http://www.iec.ch
    Model: IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGB
    Copyright: Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company
  Profile-xmp: 19368 bytes
```

Possible solution :
I would have to add the Image resource block data to such image in which the profile information is missing.

Problem :
I would have to write metadata for the tag 34377 as given in the Adobe Specification for the listed resource Id
How am I suppose to write this entire block and assign it to the Tag 34377 in C#?
What values should be added for each resource Id ?

Tiff Image : http://1drv.ms/NtzbCr

Comment: Can you specify what kind of metadata (resource ID) you want to add?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_46269 I guess these tags.

Comment: Do you know the resource id's that are required by the program?

Comment: I want to add for the Clipping path. As per the table in the above link the resource Id is 2999